How many ways are there to place 6 salamanders on a 6-by-6 grid such that no 2 salamanders share the same row, column, or diagonal?
I saw this problem on a 4th grader's math homework.
"You have a 6-by-6 grid. You must place 6 salamanders on the board such that none of them share the same row, column, or diagonal. How many ways can you do it?"
The problem would be easy if we were only concerned about row and column. Then we would actually have a formula for the number of solutions for placing n salamanders on an n-by-n grid such that none of them share the same row and column. It would just be n factorial. And you could just plug in 6 to get 6 factorial, or 720. Yet the problem asks us to be concerned with diagonals as well.
If there is some formula for the number of solutions when we are concerned with row, column, and diagonal, then that would be great. Then I could see this being a math problem that a 4th grader might be able to solve. But so far I have found no such formula. The main hurdle is that, when you place a salamander, it's diagonal is going to block a space on a different number of rows below it depending on where you place it. And when the diagonal blocks a space on a row below, it may block a space that has already been blocked, or it may block an empty space. This makes the problem incredibly complex, where you have to check a different amount of cases depending on where you place a salamander and where the previous salamanders where placed on rows above.
The only way I have found all the solutions for the 6-by-6 grid is by manually checking each of the 6 factorial solutions to the row and column problem, and counting how many of them also satisfy the diagonal constraint. But of course that is slow. So it turns from a math problem to a computing problem. So I have written a program to see how many solutions there are for each of the n-by-n grids, starting with the 1-by-1 grid and going up. And I don't see an obvious formula. Also the algorithm has the complexity of $O(n^n)$ so it effectively stops after the 15-by-15 square. At least on my machine.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in a way that a 4th grader would be able to?

This is https://oeis.org/A000170.  Having computed a few terms, you can check OEIS.  I just searched for 73712 and this was the first hit.  Congratulations-your program seems correct.  No formula is given

This question is usually asked about chess queens, not salamanders: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle . Per that article, no formula is known for general $n$. However, for small grids you can check systematically quite quickly. If you look at the solutions you found, you'll see there is really only one pattern that works: you can get the others by reflecting the grid (possibly through one of the diagonals). Using symmetry this way makes the solution space much easier to search. Perhaps that's what they were looking for with this question?

Your program claims that there are only 4 solutions. The problem must be very highly constrained. This suggests that a simple search of the space will result in most partial placements pruned early.
For example, suppose salamander 0 is at $(0,0)$.  Then salamander 1 must be at $(1,x)$ for $x≥2$. If it is at $(1,2)$ then salamander 2 is at $(2,4)$ or $(2,5)$.
$(2,4)$ forces $(3,1)$ and $(4,2)$ and then there is no $(5,?)$. $(2,5)$ forces $(3,1)$ and then $(4,?)$ fails. So $(0,0), (1,2)$ does not work.
Continuing in this way from $(0,0), (1,3)$ ought  to  be possible for a 4th grader with ordinary persistence.

Update:  Over the weekend I tried it out to see how long it would take.  It took me 23 minutes to completely exhaust the search space.  I didn't note the point at which I found the solution; I guess about 15 minutes in. (It has a salamander at $(0,1)$, so I had to exhaust the $(0,0)$ search first.)  Of course it would take a fourth-grader substantially longer, but  I stand by my guess that it should be possible.
A 4th-grader who did try this exercise would learn a lot about how to plan and execute systematic work.  Here is the complete search for positions where there is a salamander at $(0, 1)$:

The search for positions with salamanders at $(0, 0)$ is about the same size.  The search starting from $(0,2)$ was very fast because nearly all the positions were equivalent under rotation to positions I had already searched.
Note that there is really only one solution (marked ‘WIN’ in the illustration).  The other solutions are rotations and reflections of this one.
If I were assigning this to a fourth-grader, I would have a discussion with them ahead of time about why $(0,3), (0,4)$ and $(0,5)$ can be skipped.

Hi dear @MJD, why do you write all your answers in community wiki format ?

Because I want to optimize my answers for quality, rather than point-scoring. Declining the points may help me avoid conflicts of interest. Quality is important.  Points don't matter.
